# lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

When I try to pass this on to the lemmatizer like this:

```
def lemmatization(token_txt):
    text = [wn.lemmatize(word) for word in token_txt]
   # text = [[wn.lemmatize(word) for word in l] for l in token_text]
    return text

data['Tweet_lem'] = data['Tweet_sw'].apply(lambda x:lemmatization(x))
data.head()
```

i get following error

```
TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

when i let it run like this:

```
def lemmatization(token_txt):
      # text = [wn.lemmatize(word) for word in token_txt]
        text = [[wn.lemmatize(word) for word in l] for l in token_text]
        return text


data['Tweet_lem'] = data['Tweet_sw'].apply(lambda x:lemmatization(x))
data.head()
```

i get this error

> NameError: name 'token_text' is not defined

What do i have to do?

I am trying to apply the function on punctuation and stop words removed sentences. the steps stemming and tokenization are not applied.

[DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o16eG.png)

[DataSet new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcDrT.png)

[Full example first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIEPv.png)

[Full example second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdiRO.png)

Comment: could you post the first few values of `data["Tweet_sw"]`?

Comment: how about showing us data['Tweet_sw'].head(10) ?

Comment: i`ve added photo above.

Comment: Tweet_sw is not a list, it is a string, just do not call join in the previous step

Comment: Is it possible that you write me the correct code @Edge7 ? I dont know what you with the join mean.

Comment: either change the body of your remove_stopwords function like:
`return [w for w in txt_clean.split() if w not in stopwords]
`
or change the way you call lemmatize:
`data['Tweet_lem'] = data['Tweet_sw'].apply(lambda x:lemmatization(x.split()))
`
Obviously, the first approach does make more sense

Comment: Ahh, that was the previos step you talked about. There i used a join because without the output is like in the new added photo above.

i removed the join in the remove_stopwords function and running now for lemmatization: 
def lemmatization(token_txt):
     text = [wn.lemmatize(word) for word in token_txt]
     return text

data['Tweet_lem'] = data['Tweet_sw'].apply(lambda x:lemmatization(x))
data.head()

but this time i get this error in the lemmatization step: 

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: I am assuming that you want to lemmatize each word, so it makes sense to have a *list* as a result of remove_stopwords which is then the input of your lemmatization function.
The new error you got is because of indentation, which is the way you indent your Python code (https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html), I would suggest you to post a full example, otherwise here we are going nowhere (after having fixed the indentation yourself).

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me :) 

As you can easily see I'm still in the beginning and I'm also taking over large parts of the code from open source. 

I have fixed the indentation bug. Now I have another bug. 

lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

as you say, i have to save the output of the stop word removing function as a list. unfortunately i don't know how to do that

Comment: And yes, i want to lemmatize each word.

Comment: from where you have imported and initialized wn?
what happens if you call:
`wn.lemmatize("hello")`
in a new Ipython cell?

Comment: i am getting the same error, when i run that in a own cell. i have imported it "from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer as wn"

Comment: I got where the problem is, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few comments I finally understood the problem.
It is the way you import the WordNetLemmatizer, import it as follows:

`import nltk
wn = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()`

then you can use it as you have already done, i.e.:
`wn.lemmatize("hello")`

Comment: import nltk
wn = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()                                                 
nltk.download('wordnet')           <== was also needed. Thank you very much!